# Define Typescript function with optional object argument with optional attributes, all with default values

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out the best Typescript implementation of the following scenario.

I have a function `doSomething(num, config?)` that accepts a number and an optional config object that consists of a few optional parameters.

So if I define config to be of type { acceptNegative?: boolean, isBig?: boolean } then I want all the following to be valid function calls.

`doSomething(num);`

`doSomething(num, { acceptNegative: true });`

`doSomething(num, { acceptNegative: true, isBig: false });`

In addition, I want to be able to set default values for both the cases of

1. User doesn't provide config object => `doSomething(num);`
2. User provides config object with incomplete data => `doSomething(num, { acceptNegative: true });`

What's the most elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFAFCKJgiYBcVNARtgE4A0FiECwMR9Ab0QBDCBGwAHKADlsRYbABu2APz1GcOABtswsAG5EMAM4AhPmsQbtupAF9EAXkQC7HAJQu7ZMjqgNMJ0QARn0yVAwcfEJSakx3MIisXAJiEji2FxExSRk5BRhleigWEGxEOwTw9GTotIys0XEpWXklbGLS7EyTc35EYGEtY3LKsKA) work for you?

Comment: @wonderflame, in your approach the default value if config is not passed is an empty object. Ideally the default value should have all the attributes with their default values. And if the user does pass in the config object with some attributes, the rest should be set to their default values

Comment: got it. what about [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeUCGAxoRGMAHIRr7AoBuEAXFAEZxwA2E+CA3FCgDOAIXTM2nbgigBfXgCh5hRIOBQAJhCT4Arh2AA1fBx0RBzeMnRZc8qAWKkKVGvSZRtHQRAA0dgSJiHsbefnKKSDoIhLSIGnAAynAAthDAABYoCGgAFAg6ycz5ySwQAE4+UMpWaMwACvhltMYAPJaoaAB8NjgyAJS29tWqVYgdAOooGQAiWrr6RiZmPVAAdOua2nqGxqaCleur1R2yCv7DkqsccLnH6JMzc9uLe30KMopcasU2AIwK6kSKTSmWyeQKb3kgKSqQyWVyxUqeCIJDIlGotAYzGAZVMskh0OBcLBiNwDlRzgxbmxuN8AVEtSgOLx-QUQA)?

Comment: @wonderflame Wow yup that's exactly what I wanted. This also makes me wonder why I have never seen 'Partial<>' until now since I image that this use case that I described is quite typical. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's create a separate type for the `config` parameter:

```
type Config = { acceptNegative: boolean; isBig: boolean };
```

Since you expect `config` to be optional and be able to pass not all of its required properties we are going to use built-in type [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), which will turn all of the properties of the passed type into optional:

```
function doSomething(num: number, config: Partial<Config> = {}) {}
```

We will have `{}` as a default value for the `config`, and to have default values for the config's properties let's create a default config:

```
const defaultValues: Config = {
  acceptNegative: false,
  isBig: false,
};
```

Now, in the function body, we will spread `defaultValues` and `config` into a single object, where the `defaultValues` should be the first, otherwise, it would overwrite values coming from `config`:

```
function doSomething(num: number, config: Partial<Config> = {}) {
  const configWithDefaultValues = { ...defaultValues, ...config };

  console.log(configWithDefaultValues);
}
```

Usage:

```
let num = 1;
doSomething(num);
doSomething(num, { acceptNegative: true });
doSomething(num, { acceptNegative: true, isBig: true });
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeUCGAxoRGMAHIRr7AoBuEAXFAEZxwA2E+CA3FCgDOAIXTM2nbgigBfXgCh5hRIOBQAJhCT4Arh2AA1fBx0RBzeMnRZc8qAWKkKVGvSZRtHQRAA0dgSJiHsbefnKKSDoIhLSIGnAAynAAthDAABYoCGgAFAg6ycz5ySwQAE4+UMpWaMwACvhltMYAPJaoaAB8NjgyAJS29tWqVYgdAOooGQAiWrr6RiZmPVAAdOua2nqGxqaCleur1R2yCv7DkqsccLnH6JMzc9uLe30KMopcasU2AIwK6kSKTSmWyeQKb3kgKSqQyWVyxUqeCIJDIlGotAYzGAZVMskh0OBcLBiNwDlRzgxbmxuN8AVEtSgOLx-QUQA)

Comment: This is a good answer, just note that if there are more configuration options and performance is important, you might not want to use that expensive spread operator and instead get the values manually (i.e. `doSomething(config.abc ?? defaultValues.abc)`)

Comment: True,  though would be really uncomfortable in case of dozens of properties

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Config {
 acceptNegative?: boolean;
 isBig?: boolean;
}

function doSomething(num: number, config: Partial<Config> = {}): void
```

{
const { acceptNegative = false, isBig = true } = config;

// Rest of your function logic here

```
 console.log(`num: ${num}`);
 console.log(`acceptNegative: ${acceptNegative}`);
 console.log(`isBig: ${isBig}`);
 }

 // Valid function calls
 doSomething(42); // No config object provided, uses default values
 doSomething(42, { acceptNegative: true }); 
 // Config object with acceptNegative provided
 doSomething(42, { acceptNegative: true, isBig: false }); 
 // Config object with acceptNegative and isBig provided
```